# extend C drive without deleting/formatting D drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

**Windows 11 (SSD) :**

**C Drive -> Total: 264Gb -> Free: 46.8Gb**

**D Drive -> Total: 210Gb -> Free: 95.9Gb**

i want to add **30Gb more to C drive(i want to increase C drive) from D drive**

i seen solution for this in google, but they all telling deleting d drive like that.

i want to do it **withuout deleting D drive**, becuase i dont have any backup options, **becuase D drive contains almost 100+GB of files.**

any solution for this?

Comment: *If you do not have backups*, DO NOT ALTER THE PARTITIONS

Answer (score 1):

> any solution for this?

It is not practical (or even do-able) to try to span partitions across drives, so adding space from one drive to another drive cannot practically be done.

You can move documents from C: to D:  Documents, pictures, videos, email and such like.

But you cannot move Program Files, Windows and Core USERS (numerous AppData folders).

So your only practical solution here is a new, much larger main drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a tool such as "MiniTool Partition Wizard", which will allow you to change the volume size of a drive that's already formatted and partitioned and in use! But there is a catch; this is not the safest thing to do, even the software warns you before you execute the command.
Please use [this solution](https://www.partitionwizard.com/help/moveresize-volume.html#:%7E:text=Run%20MiniTool%20Partition%20Wizard%20to,of%20the%20rectangle%20bar%20leftwards.) at your own discretion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is no safe way for your data on your D: drive to do it.
So without any backup, it is highly unsafe.

Your C: drive is one partition, your D: drive is another partition but data are written all over a partition. It is not perfectly organised in "used space" and "free space".

Let’s say your D drive looks like this:

> XXX....XXXXXX..XXXX..XXX

> XXXXXXXXXXX........XXXXX

> XXXXXXXXXX.....XXX.XX.XX

With X = used space and "." = free space. Windows cannot "cut" the free-space out of your D drive.

It is only possible if your data are organised the following way on the disk:

> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

> XXXXXXXXXX......................................

and it is barely never the case unless you never erased any data from your disk and you only added data since the very beggining.

The usual method is to clear out one partition (=delete a partition, let’s say "D:") which makes free-space available (and remove Everything !!), then this free-space can be added safely to other existing partitions such as C:.

You can see your partitions in the Windows tool called "Disk Management"
==> Windows + X opens a menu in which you can select "Disk Management"

Sometimes there could be some non-allocated space on your drive that you can add to one of your existing partition safely (but that’s quite rare).

Your best shot is to buy an external hard drive, SAVE your D drive on it, then remove the D drive partition to make it "unallocated space". Allocate 30Gb to the C partition (=extend C partition) then re-created the D disk with the non-allocated space left and copy back your data on it.

Any other way implies a high risk of data loss on the D drive.
Plus, it is highly recommanded to have, at all time, a save of your data before modifying partitions. Any bug, powercut, unexpected event during the partitionning can corrupt your whole SSD and make its data unusable.